# How to create a plain view in swiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, view, swiftui, ios13

I'm trying to create a plain view with a background color in **SwiftUI**. But everything I can find are elements that are not plain views like Text, Button, Image, List, etc..

When I try to use `View`, it shows me following error messages:

> - 'View' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers
> - 'View' Protocol can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associatedType requirements

How do I create a rectangular view with background color?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just use the `Rectangle()`

As the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/rectangle) states:

> A rectangular shape aligned inside the frame of the view containing it.

Here an example of a rectangle with fixed size and background color

```swift
Rectangle()
    .size(CGSize(width: 10, height: 10))
    .foregroundColor(.red)
```

Answer (score 6):

Just in case your use case is something like creating a background for a TextField view, here's a demonstration of how I did mine

The example here will create a small view with an opaque secondary background, then render on top of it a label that signifies the user to enter a location, another white rounded rectangle, and within the white rectangle a TextField().

```
struct InputView : View {
    @State var text:          String

    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15).frame(width: 310, height: 100)
                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                .offset(y: -20)
            ZStack{
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30).frame(width: 290, height: 40)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                TextField($text, placeholder: Text("City, State, Address")) {
                        print(self.text)
                        self.didEnter.toggle()
                    }
                        .frame(width: 220, height: 40, alignment: .leading)
                        .offset(x: -20)
                Text("Select Location:").bold().fontWeight(.medium)
                    .offset(y: -40)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. The answers saying to use Rectangle are going to leave a lot of viewers wondering how to add more views to their “plain view with a background”.

Answer (score 5):

This is another way of creating something like a **UIView**. In SwiftUI, every primitive view works like a UIView.

```
struct CustomView : View {

    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Color.red.frame(width: 300, height: 300)
            Text("This is view")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in another answer, you could use Shape like `Rectangle()` and set it's `size` and `foregroundColor`:

```
Rectangle()
    .size(CGSize(width: 10, height: 10))
    .foregroundColor(.blue)
```

But I think using `Color` directly is simpler:

```
Color.blue
    .frame(width: 10, height: 10)
```