# SwiftUI view like UIKit UIView, How to change the size of the image

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Is there any view in swiftui that is similar to UIKit UIView

There is an `EmptyView` in swiftui does anyone know what this view do

```
        Image("image")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(3/2, contentMode: .fill)
```

This messes up the image is there any other way that i can resize the image

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/image

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56486345/how-to-create-a-plain-view-in-swiftui

Comment: thnx @ielyamani

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SwiftUI, primitive views like Color, Text, Image etc act like UIView. To change a image size you just need to give it a frame and make it **resizable()** first.

```
struct ContentView : View {

    var body: some View {

         Image("your image name")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
    }
}
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Are you sure about `Text` being `resizable`?

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI, to change the image size there is 2 ways

1) Make it resizable and give some frame to Image

```
   Image("image name")
      .resizable()
      .frame(width: 10, height: 10, alignment: .center)
```

2) Make it resizable and scaleToFit property to Image

```
   Image("image name")
      .resizable()
      .scaledToFit()
```

For more customization of Image please look at below link
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/image/3269652-frame

I hope it will help you!!